# Как расстянуть ссылку на весь блок?

Tags: css, html5

как мне расстянуть ссылку так, чтобы на неё можно было кликнуть по бэкграунду тэга li? display: block для ссылок не работает.

```css
.product-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #ccffff;
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    
   
}

.product-list {
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
}

.product-list li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid #666666 1px;
    background: #fff;
}


.product-list a {
    
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-menu">
                        <ul class="product-list">
                                
                         
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: width: 100 процентов

Comment: Это же элементарно. Во первых, если ссылка - FLEX, то ей нужно прописать растяжение: `flex: 1;`. Ну а во вторых, она никогда не растянется на всю высоту, пока у нее `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, применить к тегу `a` `width: 100%` и `text-align: center`;

**UPD.** Для того, чтобы его растянуть на весь блок, нужно также установить `height: 100%` и убрать `margin-top`.

```css
.product-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #ccffff;
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    
   
}

.product-list {
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
}

.product-list li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid #666666 1px;
    background: #fff;
}


.product-list a {
    
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-menu">
                        <ul class="product-list">
                                
                         
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, ещё добавил height: 100%, но теперь проблема в том, что текст ссылки прибит к верху родительского элемента и если указываю ему margin для сдвига в центр, то целая ссылка уходит вниз. Новая проблема: как теперь сделать текст ссылки по центру?

Comment: Смотри ответ ниже - всё по центру

Answer (score 0):

Там в предыдущем ответе стиль ссылки не правильно задан, свойства флексов для блоков не работают или работают не корректно, смотри свойства ссылки и там всё отмечено, где и чт добавить и поменять

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .product-menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #ccffff;
        width: 70%;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 2%;
      }

      .product-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }

      .product-list li {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        border: solid #666666 1px;
        background: #fff;
      }

      .product-list a {
        display: flex; /*тут block не надо align-items и justify-content свойства флексов */
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center; /*вот тут добавить ещё свойство и всё будет как надо*/
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px red solid;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="product-menu">
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы убрал все из `li` и перенес в `a`. В коде закомментировал всё, что убрал, и отметил, что добавил в `a`. Как я понял, красная рамка вокруг текста, была для примера, ее тоже убрал.

```css
.product-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #ccffff;
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 2%;
}

.product-list {
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
}

.product-list li {
/*     display: flex; */
/*     justify-content: center; */
/*     height: 30px; */
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 30px; /* Заменил height на min-height */
    border: solid #666666 1px;
    background: #fff;
}


.product-list a {
  
    
    display: block;
/*     align-items: center; */
/*     margin-top: 6px; */
/*     border: 1px red solid; */
  
/*   Добавил */
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
  
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-menu">
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень рекомендую почитать, как работает FLEX-модуль в HTML/CSS.

```css
.product-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #ccffff;
  height: 500px;
}

.product-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.product-list li {
  width: 100px; height: 30px;
  border: solid #666666 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

.product-list a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-menu">
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```